# Why does custom Build Process Template executing PowerShell fail

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, powershell-3.0

I've modified a custom build process template to execute Powershell on the build server.   This is so I can run some scripts that will automate the deployment of our SharePoint solution.  Everything was working fine up until I upgraded the build servers Powershell version from 2.0 to 3.0 (which needed to be done as I was installing SCVMM Admin Console 2012 and Powershell 3.0 was a pre-requisite).

In the build template itself, I'm using a **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess** work flow item to execute the PowerShell command with the following properties:

> Arguments : String.Format(" ""& '{0}' -DropLocation '{1}' {2} "" ",
>   ScriptFilename, BuildDetail.DropLocation, PostDropScript2Arguments)
>
> FileName : "powershell"
>
> OutputEncoding :
>   System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)

Now every time I try to execute the build, I get the following error:

> Exception Message: File not found: PowerShell (type
>   FileNotFoundException) Exception Stack Trace:  Server stack trace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.ProcessWrapper.Start()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.InvokeProcessInternal.RunCommand(AsyncState
>   state)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)    at System.Func`2.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: The system cannot find the file specified (type
>   Win32Exception) Exception Stack Trace:    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.ProcessWrapper.Start()

It seems like the build is no longer able to link the "powershell" command with the actual PowerShell file.

I've manually gone onto the build server and typed "powershell" into a command line and it started PowerShell, as expected.

Has anyone else experienced this issue before?

Thanks very much

Comment: Is it possible that the environment variables simply haven't refreshed? I.e., have you restarted the build windows service or server since the installation?

Comment: @Nathan thanks for the input, I had to restart the build server after the installation of the new version of Powershell so unfortunately I don't believe that is the issue. I will give it another try though!

Comment: I have just seen exactly the same problem.  Using *any* other method I can think of (including LinqPad and `Process.Invoke`, each under the build account), I can launch PowerShell without a path - but the build process suddenly cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the full filepath to powershell.exe in the invokeprocess step in your workflow and it should always work (I would not trust the environment-settings for this)
And know, logging in on the server under your own account is not equal to the build server running under a specific account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You make some good points - Funnily enough I actually managed to get the build working again this morning.  The only thing I actually changed was to create a new Build Agent and get the build definition to use that and then it started working again.  I will try your suggestion of explicitly targeting the path in the workflow and if that works will mark this as the answer.

Comment: I changed the FileName argument to be "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" and it worked great.  Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: I had the same problem - I had to create a new build Controller (not agent!) for the issue to be resolved.  It seems that it's caching something somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

In my case same error occurred after deploying Windows Managment Framework 3.0.
It was solved by restarting build controller and agent.